# In D3, how to update global value by a Asynchronous function?

Tags: d3.js, load-csv, asynchronous-javascript

I defined an empty variable dataset:
var dataset = [];
Load data from a .csv file by d3.dsv function, the schema likes

```
d3.dsv(",", "filename.csv", function(d){
 return {
  key1: value,
  key2: value,
  ...
};
}).then(function(d) {
 //do something like dataset = d to update dataset;
});
```

My goal is to update the global value dataset I defined at the beginning by .then() function, so I can use the updated dataset later, and it's outside of .then() function. What I can do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score -1):

You have access to global scope from any other scope

```
window.dataset = null // define global variable
d3.dsv(",", "filename.csv", function(d){
 return {
  key1: value,
  key2: value,
  ...
};
}).then(function(d) {
 //do something like dataset = d to update dataset;
 window.dataset = d // assign 'd' to 'dataset'
});
```

Comment: console.log(dataset) still printed null. The value did not change.

Comment: what about `console.log(window.dataset)`?

Comment: The same output null